# Find the index from values in a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Does any one knows how to get the index of the values from dictionary 2 on dictionary 1.. like this:

```
Dictionary_1= {A: [Tom, Jane, Joe]; B: [Joana, Clare, Tom]; C: [Clare, Jane, Joe]}

Dictionary_2 = {A: Tom; B: Clare; C: Jane}

RESULT = {A: 1; B: 2; C: 2}
```

EDIT:
Sorry guys.. first of all I got confused and forgot that I needed it starting with "0" instead of "1".
I was having a problem, but it was because my list inside of dictionary 1 was in unicode format instead of list.

Also.. in the example I used here, I noticed later that the keys existed in both dictionaries, but in the code Im writting it wasnt the same thing. I didnt post the original here because it was bigger, so I tried to resume the most I could. Sorry for that too.

So I got it working with this code:

```
            RESULT = {}
            for x, y in Dictionary_1.items():
                for a, b in Dictionary_2 .items():
                    if x == a:
                        z = Dictionary_1[x]
                        r = eval(z)
                        if '{0}'.format(b) in r:
                            RESULT [a] = r.index('{0}'.format(b))
```

I know that its looks messy but im still learning.
I really appreciate your help guys!

Comment: I think I know how. But have you tried it? we'd like to see your attempt, please post the code and we can help you with it - this is how this site works!

Comment: Python is zero indexed, so your desired result looks off by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want 0-based indices, you can use [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) with a [dict comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html):

```
d1 = {'A': ['Tom', 'Jane', 'Joe'], 'B': ['Joana', 'Clare', 'Tom'], 'C': ['Clare', 'Jane', 'Joe']}

d2 = {'A': 'Tom', 'B': 'Clare', 'C': 'Jane'}

result = {k: d1[k].index(v) for k, v in d2.items()}

print(result)
# {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}
```

If you want to have indices starting at `1`, then you can do `d1[k].index(v) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using *dict comprehension*.

```
dict1={'A':['Tom','Jane','Joe'],'B':['Joana','Clare','Tom'],'C':['Clare','Jane','Joe']}
dict2={'A':'Tom','B':'Clare','C':'Jane'}
result={k:dict1[k].index(v)+1 for k,v in dict2.values()}
# {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 2}
#Or
# {k:dict1.get(k).index(v)+1 for k,v in dict2.items()}
```

Comment: Haha I guess we both did the same thing ;)

Comment: @RoadRunner But I was seconds late. ;)

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand solution for you

```
d1 = {'A': ['Tom', 'Jane', 'Joe'], 'B': ['Joana', 'Clare', 'Tom'], 'C': ['Clare', 'Jane', 'Joe']}
d2 = {'A': 'Tom', 'B': 'Clare', 'C': 'Jane'}

output = {}
for k,v in d2.items():
    output[k] = d1[k].index(v)+1

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the best approach but this is what I did quickly:

```
dict1 = {0: ['Tom', 'Jane', 'Joe'], 1: ['Joana', 'Clare', 'Tom'], 2: ['Clare', 'Jane', 'Joe']}
dict2 ={0: 'Tom', 1: 'Clare', 2: 'Jane'}
result = {}

val_list = list(dict1.values())

for i in range(0,len(dict1)):
    result.update({i : val_list[i].index(dict2[i])})

print(result)
```